# Jquery toggle multiple div with same id

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I use jQuery to toggle divs.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnstoreofferlisting-3").click(function(){
        $("#storeofferlisting-3").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

I have more div with "storeofferlisting-3" id. I click to "#btnstoreofferlisting-3" button, but only one div hide and show.
How can I make it to working with all same id divs?

Comment: try using class instead of id as id should be unique

Answer (score 1):

First of all, IDs should be unique. You should only have one ID per page.
Change the IDs to classes.

Once you do that your code will be something like this:

```
$(".btnstoreofferlisting-3").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/

Answer (score 0):

use css class

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myDiv").click(function(){
        $(".myDiv").toggle();
   });
});
</script>
```